# iOS - UIPageControl cuts bottom off

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uipageviewcontroller

I'm creating a `UIViewControl` with [this](http://www.appcoda.com/uipageviewcontroller-storyboard-tutorial/) this website. I finished it, but when I load my image, the bottom of my image gets cut off. I'm sure the dimensions of the image are correct, besides the `UIImageView` is stretched throughout whole screen.

Since the whole code is on the site, I won't be adding anything here, except for one line I changed.

I changed

```
self.pageViewController.view.frame = 
    CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width,
               self.view.frame.size.height - 30);
```

to

```
self.pageViewController.view.frame = 
    CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 
               self.view.frame.size.height);
```

The gap got smaller but is still there. It looks like this

[image: Gap between imageview and end of screen]

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Have you taken into account the height of the status bar at the top of the phone?

I think that in iOS 7 the status bar overlaps the content by default, you might have to slide the content down a bit.

Comment: Thats what i thought. I slides it down a bit. What happened was that a white gap was created at top due to the moving, but the bottom gap stayed the same with the same height. Also, when I set a black tab bar in storyboard, after compiling it gets overridden and becomes white again. I think its something in the code but I can't find it.